# Getting #NUM error using MOD function in excel (to find remainder) when the divisor is high

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use the MOD function to determine the remainder when an expression 2^n - n^2 is divided by 6. It's all good till n= 42 but n=43 onwards I get a #NUM error. Is this only because the value of the expression is too big after n= 42?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely size, but you don't need to tax excel to get these values. Notice the pattern: (1,0,5,0,1,4)